# In CNF $A \models (p ∧ A[p/1]) ∨ (¬p ∧ A[p/0])$ and $(p ∧ A[p/1]) ∨ (¬p ∧ A[p/0])\models A $

Tags: logic

So from  right to left .

I said when $p \land A[p/1]$ is fulfilled then there is an assignment $\psi$ such that $\psi (p)=1$ and $\psi(A[p/1])=1$ so we choose an assignemnt $\psi'$with $\psi'(p)=1$ and $\psi'=\psi$ else. This assignment fulfills $A$ per Definition.
The other case is practically the same.

Im stuck at the other part of the implication. I feel like i could try induction but how can i use induction over CNF ?

Comment: "so we choose an assignemnt $ψ′$ .." But we have to prove that: "if $\psi$ fulfils $p∧A[p/1]$, then $\psi$ fulfils $A$".

Comment: Consider $\psi \vDash (p∧A[p/1])∨(¬p∧A[p/0])$; then eitehr $\psi$ fulfils $p∧A[p/1]$ or it fulfils $¬p∧A[p/0]$. In the firts case: $\psi(p)=1$ **and** $\psi(A[p/1])=1$. But when $\psi(p)=1$, then $\psi(A[p/1])=\psi(A)=1$, and thus $\psi \vDash A$. The same for the other subcase.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ok i got it thank you, how about proving the other side ? I feel like it is pretty similiar, does being in CNF even have an effect on this exercise ?

Comment: It seems to me not to... If $\psi(A)=1$, then either $\psi(p)=1$ and thus $\psi(A[p/1])=\psi(A)=1$, or  $\psi(p)=0$ and thus $\psi(\lnot p)=1$ and $\psi(A[p/0)])=\psi(A)=1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you can copy and paste the comments as an answer  so i can accept your answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st part:

Consider $\psi$ such that: $ψ⊨(p∧A[p/1])∨(¬p∧A[p/0])$; then, eitehr $ψ$ fulfils $p∧A[p/1]$ or it fulfils $¬p∧A[p/0]$.

In the first case: $ψ(p)=1$ and $ψ(A[p/1])=1$.

But when $ψ(p)=1$, we have that: $ψ(A)=ψ(A[p/1])=1$, and thus $ψ⊨A$.

The same for the other subcase.

2nd part:

Assume $ψ⊨A$, i.e. $ψ(A)=1$.

Either $ψ(p)=1$, and thus $ψ(A[p/1])=ψ(A)=1$, or $ψ(p)=0$, and thus $ψ(¬p)=1$ and $ψ(A[p/0)])=ψ(A)=1$.